# Comparing arrays content, difference of SequenceEqual and StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have 2 arrays :

```
        int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I need to check if they are equal ( not by ref)

What is the difference between writing :

```
        Console.WriteLine(arr1.SequenceEqual(arr2)); //true
```

vs

```
        IStructuralEquatable eqArray1 = arr1;
        Console.WriteLine(eqArray1.Equals(arr2, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer));  //true
```

both returns True..

When should I use each ?

Comment: IStructuralEquatable gives feature to check equality as well as comparision of two arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `SequenceEqual` is kind of similar::

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator1 = first.GetEnumerator())
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
    {
        if (!enumerator2.MoveNext() || !comparer.Equals(enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (enumerator2.MoveNext())
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

This default `SequenceEqual` method use default `EqualityComparer<int>.Default` for `int` which is value equality.

`Array` implement `IStructuralEquatable` with `Equal` method:

```
bool IStructuralEquatable.Equals(object other, IEqualityComparer comparer)
{
    if (other == null) return false;

    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
        Array array = other as Array;
        if ((array == null) || (array.Length != this.Length))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            object x = this.GetValue(i);
            object y = array.GetValue(i);

            if (!comparer.Equals(x, y))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The `IEqualityComparer` from input parameter is used, in here you input `StructruralEqualityComparer` but `int` does not implement `IStructruralEquatable`, so it uses default comparer for `int` which is value equality.

But, needless to input `StructruralEqualityComparer` because `int` is not structural, you should just use:

```
(arr1 as IStructuralEquatable).Equals(arr2, EqualityComparer<int>.Default);
```

It still works. You should use `StructruralEqualityComparer` if item in array is *structrural*

So to sum up, the implementation for both is kind of the same, both iterate two array based on value equality of `int` to make comparison.

I would prefer the LINQ verson since it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a related question and saw that this question was never actually answered properly. There is a difference between the structural and the sequence - the first comparison is deep and the second one is not.

This simple code demonstrates and produces `True` `False`:

```
int[][] ints1 = { new int[] { 3, 4 } };
int[][] ints2 = { new int[] { 3, 4 } };
Console.WriteLine(StructuralComparisons.
                          StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(ints1, ints2));
Console.WriteLine(ints1.SequenceEqual(ints2));
```

The name "sequence" suggests one-dimensionalism so the name choice is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Standard equality checks in .NET uses EqualityComparer.Default for comparisons. For example dictionaries or SequenceEqual method you have written there uses EqualityComparer.Default by default. And that comparer either uses Equals(object) method or Equals(T) method in presence of IEquatable interface implementation.

But you can always give other comparers like StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer to dictionaries or methods such as SequenceEqual.

So, the main difference between two methods is the equality check method they use. SequenceEqual uses IEquatable interface method for checks, and StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer uses IStructuralEquatable interface method for checks. And as a result, default equality checks need two of the compared items to be the same type but StructuralEqualityComparer doesn't require them to be same type. As the name suggests it is supposed to compare contents.

Answer (score 0):

The linq version is the most flexible, it can compare two enumerables.
The StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer version require that the two collections can support the IStructuralEquatable interface.  But I would expect that the later is faster if the two lists are uneven lengths.

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class StructuralEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T> where T : IStructuralEquatable {
    public override bool Equals(T? x, T? y) {
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T x) {
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think System.Linq is your friend:

```
bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Thanks but I asked what is the difference. And when should I use which...:-)